# WebRTC identify remote stream video stop

Tags: android, sockets, webrtc

I have integrate successfully video call using WebRTC in android with this dependency,

```
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.21217'
```

In app if video capture is stopped for remote video stream then at receiver side new frames are also stopped. But now I want to identify if remote stream is stopped to display a message to receiver side.

Is it possible with webrtc events? Can anyone guide me with code or any link ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to know if the video has been stooped from the android client or from the remote client ? Your question is a bit confusing. If you stop the video on your local device cant you also send a message to the receiver that the video was stooped on the same event you literally stop the video? If you mean you stop remote video and you get black frames instead of video and want to put an image, again can't you just send a message on the socket(I'm assuming you are using socket) when you stop the video?And also how do you stop the video stream ? As I am aware you can do
`stream.getVideoTracks.get(0).setEnable(false)` . I assume you are refering to this, on android side. If you geve me some details I would gladly help :)

Comment: Let me explain my question. If local video stream is stopped then I want to inform all other peers that video is stopped from this user. I can send an event to socket if user is stopping video. But in case of connectivity drop I can not send event instantly to other peers. Currently I am saving timestamp of last frame of remote peer and comparing it with current timestamp to check if new frame received. But it can downgrade app performance in case of number of peers increased.

Comment: for connection interruptions you might want to look into the RTCPeerConnection iceConnectionState and its associated iceconnectionstatechange event